# IE Web Automation - How to auto select value from combo box using Excel VBA/XML Macro

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, browser-automation, webautomation

I'm a beginner in VBA and I've failed to select country name automatically in web Combo box or list box from my Excel spreadsheet. My code is entering country name only, but not selecting it. 
How can I change this code so it can pick country name from my Excel spreadsheet and select the same in web combo box as a loop. Passport number, DOB and Nationality are correct on my code. If you'll use manually then you can find the work permit number which I need to capture in my spreadsheet. Chrome Inspect Element screenshot is attached herewith.

[image: Screenshot]

My code is as follows:

```
Sub MOL()
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Buttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Button As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim Tags As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim Alltext As IHTMLElementCollection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://eservices.mol.gov.ae/SmartTasheel/Complain/IndexLogin?lang=en-gb"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop

Set Doc = IE.document
Set Buttons = Doc.getElementsByTagName("Button")
Buttons(2).Click
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3: Loop
Set HTMLInputs = Doc.getElementsByTagName("Input")
    HTMLInputs(46).Value = "somevalue"
    HTMLInputs(48).Value = "24/02/1990"
    HTMLInputs(47).Value = "India"
Buttons(21).Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you scraping information about 20,000 work permits from a government site?   I'm pretty sure that's against the sites TOU and therefore is **not allowed to be asked here**.   Also, if this is your code (since "you forgot to choose country') then just go back and fix it the same way you wrote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you look for is a bit difficult to provide. There are few tricky parts to hurdle to select the `NATIONALITY` from dropdown. I've used `.querySelector()` within the script to make it concise. However, it should serve your purpose no matter whatever country you wanna select from dropdown. Give it a shot:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument, post As Object, URL$

    URL = "https://eservices.mol.gov.ae/SmartTasheel/Complain/IndexLogin?lang=en-gb"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document

        HTML.getElementById("TransactionInfo_WorkPermitNumber").innerText = "2659558"
        HTML.querySelector("button[ng-click='showEmployeeSearch()']").Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")  ''If for some reason the script fails, make sure to increase the delay

        HTML.getElementById("txtPassportNumber").Value = "J2659558"
        HTML.getElementById("Nationality").Focus
        For Each post In HTML.getElementsByClassName("ng-scope")
            With post.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding")
                For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                    If .item(I).innerText = "INDIA" Then ''you can change the country name here to select from dropdown
                        .item(I).Click
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next I
            End With
        Next post
        HTML.getElementById("txtBirthDate").Value = "24/02/1990"
        HTML.querySelector("button[onclick='SearchEmployee()']").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object library
```

When you execute the above script, it should give you the desired result.

Another way would be to go for using `xmlhttp` request which is way faster than IE. You need to pass the `query string parameter` arguments as dictionary through "POST" request. If you want to change the parameter as in, `birth date`,`passport`or `nationality` just do it in the `QueryString`. Btw, the `Nationality` parameter should be filled in with `value` instead of `name` as in, `100` for `INDIA.`  This is how your script should look like:

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim res As Variant, QueryString$, ID$, Name$

    QueryString = "{""PersonPassportNumber"":""J2659558"",""PersonNationality"":""100"",""PersonBirthDate"":""24/02/1990""}"

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "POST", "https://eservices.mol.gov.ae/SmartTasheel/Dashboard/GetEmployees", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send QueryString
        res = .responseText
    End With

    ID = Split(Split(Split(res, "Employees"":")(1), "ID"":""")(1), """,")(0)
    Name = Split(Split(Split(res, "Employees"":")(1), "OtherData2"":""")(1), """}")(0)

    [A1] = ID: [B1] = Name
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, V6.0
```

Running the above script, you should get the `NAME` and `ID` of your required search.

Comment: Btw, if you use `Option Explicit` on top, make sure to use this line `Dim I as long`.

Comment: Waaaaooo, SIM you did it. So happy so glad. Thank you so much. Really really appreciate. You are simply amazing. Please recommend me any book/webpage/video to learn web scrapping.

Comment: SIM can you change this macro in XML?

Comment: Glad it worked!! Don't forget to tick the grayed out checkmark between the up/down buttons next to my answer to select it as the accepted solution. If it is hard for you then check it out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Did you mean using `xmlhttp` request instead of `IE`?

Comment: I clicked the green tick mark. Thanks I didn't know. Yes xmlhttp. I heard its very fast. And please recommend me some website to learn advance  level of web scraping.

Comment: I've added another solution coming from `xmlhttp` request.

Comment: And how can I make loop for this code to capture IDs for multiple rows? both in VBA and XML?

Comment: I don't know if this link will be helpful for you to learn. However, [check out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8&index=52&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: If you want to get further help you should create another post describing your current requirement. You can create as many post as you want as long as those posts' maintain this site's standard.Thanks.

Comment: SIM can I get your whatsapp number or email ID to get some help?

Comment: @SIM How did you know which post string to use or even that is was availabe? Did you inspect web traffic or was there documentation somewhere please?

Comment: First open the dev tools by right clicking on the mouse choosing inspect element from the options. Click on the `Network Tab` then again click on the `XHR Tab`. Now, fill in all the necessary inputs in that webpage to populate results. When you hit the search button you should see a link in the `Name` panel located in the left sided area under `XHR tab`. Then click on that link and toggle your activity on `Headers`,`Preview`,`Response` tabs located right side of the box. Where you should see the stuffs you wish to know about. hope it helps.

Comment: Can you help me to resolve this problem as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999540/ie-web-automation-how-to-enter-catcha-while-using-new-xmlhttp-post-request-met